# MDX: group by with LastPeriods group by, Mondrian Schema: levelType hours

Tags: mdx, cube, mondrian

I'm new to MDX and Mondrian and have two time related questions:

**1.)**

The MDX command

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Country].[Country].Members} ON COLUMNS, [Time].[2012].[Q1 2012].[2].[2012-02-08]:[Time].[2012].[Q4 2012].[11].[2012-11-08] ON ROWS FROM [MyCube] WHERE {[Measures].[Sales]}
```

prints the result grouped by days:

```
2012-02-08 | 2873 | 9829 | ...
2012-02-09 | ...
```

**But I want to define the date range in days and get the result grouped by months**:

```
2012-02 | 34298| ...
2012-03 | ...
```

**2.)**

The Mondrian schema documentation lists the time level types *TimeYears*, *TimeQuarters*, *TimeMonths* and *TimeDays*. **Is it possible to define hours too?**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1)
The [range function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Range.html) in MDX returns members of the level you're using. In your case :

```
 [Time].[2012].[Q1 2012].[2].[2012-02-08]:[Time].[2012].[Q4 2012].[11].[2012-11-08]
```

You're using days so that's why you're getting all days. Use month instead of days in your range function. In case you do not want the data before the 8th, an option would be using a subselect to filter :

```
 SELECT
    NON EMPTY {[Country].[Country].Members} ON COLUMNS,
    [Time].[Your month level].members} ON ROWS
 FROM (
     SELECT 
        {[Measures].[Sales]} ON 0,
        [Time].[2012].[Q1 2012].[2].[2012-02-08]:[Time].[2012].[Q4 2012].[11].[2012-11-08] ON 1,
     FROM [MyCube] )
```

2) Don't know for Mondrian, but in any case you can create a time dimension based on an 'existing' table

Comment: 1.) Mondrian doesn't support sub-queries (see http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/MONDRIAN-980) so I will have to go with your first suggestion.

2.) Grrrr, I had a typo in the configuration: I used "TimeHour" instead of the plural "TimeHours" and got errors in the logfile. The latter works fine.

Thank you!